# {"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."} error during accessing SharePoint site shared Folder files

Tags: error, authentication, sharepoint-site

```
            string siteUrl1 = "https://#######.sharepoint.com/sites/####";
            string clientID = "#####################################";
            string clientSecret = "##########################";
            using (ClientContext ctx = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl1, clientID, clientSecret))
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web, p => p.Title);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();



                Console.WriteLine(ctx.Web.Title);   
                
                
                Console.WriteLine("sharepoint Accessed Done");
            }
```

Error is:

[image]

Comment: Please describe how you have registered app for client id and secret key and what xml you have used for provisioning permission ?

Comment: please try out this sample https://github.com/pnp/pnpcore/tree/dev/samples/PnP.Core.Transformation.ConsoleSample